# django returning author user name for a post

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts",on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
```

In views.py file I tried to return the posts for the user I am looking at according to a specific filter(everything works fine so far), so:

```
class UserPosts(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    template_name = "posts/user_post_list.html"
    def get_queryset(self):
            self.y= self.model.objects.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username"))
            return self.y.filter(message__icontains="jk")
```

Then I tried to use the user name(author of this post inside my template) so I tried (also this worked) :

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)  
        context["post_user"] = self.kwargs.get("username")
        return context
```

Then I thought of another way to do the (get_context_data method) .

I thought it should work but it did not... I don't know why!!! so here is the code that  did not work and through me an error:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)  
        context["post_user"] = self.y.username
        return context
```

The error is:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'username'
```

So why I am not able to get the username through the model?? I know this is wrong but what is the right way to extract the username for these posts from the model not by using the slug of the url;I mean `context["post_user"] = self.kwargs.get("username")`

Sorry if that was long but I tried to be clear as possible..Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `self.y` is a queryset:

```
self.y= self.model.objects.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username"))
```

When you do this: `self.y.username` you're actually trying to retrieve `username` from a `queryset` which will raise obviously an error.

If you tend to catch the `username` from **Post** `queryset` `self.y` which is the `posts_list` of a specific user, the following will output the username:

```
context["post_user"] = self.y.first().user.username
```

> But It's better to use `context["post_user"] = self.kwargs.get("username")` you already know that.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..I was really confused..you are 100% right..Really appreciate you explaining this...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't understand your question, but why aren't you using `Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)`* inside of your view instead of messing with the model?

*assuming the user you want is the requesting user.

Comment: Hi,thanks for responding but (user=request.user) will return the current user who is logged in now..imagine a page have many post with many authors when I click any user I will be directed to a page that will list all of his posts ..Thats why I dont use  user=request.user.